# JPA layer giving null pointer exception while callinf find method of entity manager

Tags: java, jpa

I am using Maven+Spring+jpa for building a web based application.
I am using AbdtractDao class using EntityManager as follows

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public abstract class AbstractDao<T> {
    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AbstractDao.class);
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "entityManager")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractDao(Class<T> entityClass) {

        this.entityClass = entityClass;
        logger.info("####################### Inside constructor"+entityClass);
    }

    public AbstractDao() {
    }

    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return this.entityManager;
    }

    public void create(T entity) {
        this.entityManager.persist(entity);
    }

    public void edit(T entity) {
        this.entityManager.merge(entity);
    }

    public void remove(T entity) {
        this.entityManager.remove(this.entityManager.merge(entity));
    }

    public T find(Long primaryKey) {
        return this.entityManager.find(entityClass, primaryKey);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        CriteriaQuery cq = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        return this.entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }

}
```

When I call find method it gives me null pointer exception:
My Dao class is:

```
@Repository
public class CurrentUserDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<CurrentUser>{

}
```

Service Is:

```
@Service
public class CurrentUserServiceImpl implements CurrentUserService{
    CurrentUser currentUser = null;

    private CurrentUserDaoImpl currentUserDao = new CurrentUserDaoImpl();

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void insertCurrentUser(CurrentUser currentUser) {

    }

    @Override
    public CurrentUser getCurrentUser(Long userId) {
        currentUser = currentUserDao.find(userId);
        return currentUser;
    }

}
```

Service Interface is:

```
      public interface CurrentUserService {
            public void insertCurrentUser(CurrentUser currentUser);
            public CurrentUser getCurrentUser(Long userId);
        }
```

And calling point is:

```
    CurrentUser currentUser = new CurrentUser();
    currentUser = currentUserService.getCurrentUser(userId);
```

Please suggest some solution..
Insertion is working fine, but it is giving error in getting data only.

Comment: maybe user does not exist?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Comment: In this case, I suggest the use of `@Configurable` on your entity class (or Spring Roo, which does that for you).

Comment: I'm curious. Why are you using Spring? I thought Java EE since version 6 had standardised everything Spring once was used for.

Comment: User exists, Martin: Project is already developed in spring

Comment: chrylis: I tried using @Configurable on my entity class, but still giving me NPE

Comment: @SwapnilWalivkar And are you compiling with AspectJ like `@Configurable` requires, with the Spring aspects included?

Comment: @MartinAndersson Java EE has standardized a lot of stuff, but Spring is still better on many fronts. In this case, all of the JPA annotations *are* Java EE, but Java EE still doesn't work with patterns like Active Record, where a newly-constructed object needs a `PersistenceContext`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `CurrentUser` class to `AbstractDao` class. Using `super` you should pass it.

```
@Repository
public class CurrentUserDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<CurrentUser>{

    public CurrentUserDaoImpl(){
      super(CurrentUser.class);
    }

}
```

Otherwise the `entityClass` of `AbstractDao` will be `null`.

```
public abstract class AbstractDao<T> {
  // You need to initialize this field from sub class.
  private Class<T> entityClass;

   public AbstractDao(Class<T> entityClass) {
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
   }
 }
```

Comment: I think, debug is now only solution

Comment: Itried dibugging.It is giving NPE on
return this.entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
line of following method:

 public T find(Long primaryKey) {
     logger.info("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<,, Entity class is: "+entityClass);
     logger.info("--------------------------,, primary key is: "+primaryKey);
        return this.entityManager.find(entityClass, primaryKey);
    }

Comment: Perhaps log is fine, class object is printing and primary key is also printing.I can't figure out where I am going wrong

Comment: Sory, My bad. Actual line is : this.entityManager.find(entityClass, primaryKey);

Comment: It shows that entitymanager class object is null, how to initialize the entity manager class?

Comment: That is initialize at `persistence.xml`. Look at that file and see what is wrong.

Comment: EntityManager while insertion operation is not null but for retrieval operation it is null. Why so?